# Illegal instruction on executing PROT_EXEC page, created by mmap

Tags: c, mmap, raspberry-pi4

I'm developing a loader|linker for ELF-format object files. I use *mmap()* for mapping the code section to the process. The idea is to load and modify the relocations in the code section. But I encountered a problem of instability when using *mmap()* in PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE mode.

The simple program is `bx lr`. The code is for .arm `1e ff 2f e1`. If I load and execute it from file (four bytes - 1e ff 2f e1), everything is fine.

```
        int fd = open("bx.cod", 0, 0);
        char *p = mmap(0, len, PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        close(fd);
        proce = (System_RBProc)p;
        (*proce)();
```

But if I allocate and modify memory (writing the same code - `1e ff 2f e1`), I sometimes get `Illegal instruction`

```
        char *p = mmap(0, len, PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
        memcpy(p, "\x1e\xff\x2f\xe1", 4);
        rc = mprotect(p, len, PROT_EXEC);
        proce = (System_RBProc)p;
        (*proce)();
```

Unstability means that `Illegal instruction` is a rare occasion in the last case. But ...

Comment: Are you checking `mmap` and `mprotect` for failure?

Comment: I'm not an ARM expert, but aren't there various cache flushing things you have to do for this sort of "self modifying code"?  https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/caches-and-self-modifying-code suggests `__clear_cache()`.  If the previous contents of that memory are already in instruction cache, your attempt to overwrite it won't necessarily propagate from data to instruction cache.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Nate Eldredge, there was the cache coherence problem (sure not software bug). The solution is to set PROT_EXEC flag AFTER code modifications. In this case only the final code version is copied to instruction cache.

```
char *p = mmap(0, len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
memcpy(p, "\x1e\xff\x2f\xe1", 4);
rc = mprotect(p, len, PROT_EXEC);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following solution demonstrates stable behaviour:

```
char *p;
posix_memalign(&p, pagesize, len);
memcpy(p, "\x1e\xff\x2f\xe1", 4);
rc = mprotect(p, len, PROT_EXEC);
proce = (System_RBProc)p;
(*proce)();
```

I can only assume a software bug in raspberry pi4 `mmap()` implementation, `posix_memalign()` routine is free of such problems.

Comment: A bug seems really unlikely, `mmap` is a very heavily used and tested kernel function.  I strongly suspect the problem is in your code, and the fact that it appears to work with `posix_memalign` is coincidence.

Comment: Yes, it really seems unlikely, my experience shows that 100% such assumptions are resulted in my new code. But I have no other explanation for now.