# mmap and instruction / data cache coherency: Why can we copy and run shared libraries?

Tags: linux, arm, mmap

[On ARM after writing instructions to memory a memory barrier is needed before executing the instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354237/illegal-instruction-on-executing-prot-exec-page-created-by-mmap). Specifically clean the data cache, invalidate the instruction cache, then execute an instruction sync barrier (`ISB`) on the CPU that will execute the code.

One can use `cp` to copy an executable or shared library then execute without an explicit memory barrier. This amounts to:

1. Open the file.
2. Write to the file with `write`.
3. Close the file.
4. Open the file.
5. Map the file with `mmap` with `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC`.
6. Execute the code.

Likewise one can presumably use `mmap` to write to the file:

1. Open file.
2. Map the file with `mmap` with `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE` an `MAP_SHARED`.
3. Write to the with normal memory writes.
4. Unmap the file with `munmap`.
5. Close the file.
6. Open the file.
7. Map the file with `mmap` with `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC`
8. Execute the code.

So where in above steps is the necessary cache manipulation hiding? Is it in `munmap` or in `mmap`? Assume there is no disk access.

Presumably if neither `munmap` or `mmap` are called between writing and execution explicit cache synchronisation is needed with a call to `__clear_cache`, but can this done with either mapping?

Comment: *Assume there is no disk access.* Then where does the data go when it's written?  Where does it come from when it's `mmap()`'d?

Comment: @AndrewHenle This could be on tmpfs, or still in the page cache waiting to be written to disk. Obviously if `mmap` reads from disk, it's `mmap`'s job to keep caches coherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by the `mmap` system call.  When you map pages executable, the kernel has to ensure that when the system call returns, those pages are ready to execute.

To do its work, `mmap` will have to update the page table.  In the function [`__set_pte_at`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6d796c50f84ca79f1722bb131799e5a5710c4700/arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable.h#L323), which I presume from its name is called whenever a page table entry is updated, we have a call to [`__sync_icache_dcache`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6d796c50f84ca79f1722bb131799e5a5710c4700/arch/arm64/mm/flush.c#L51), which, if you trace it down, should eventually execute the relevant `ic` and `dc` instructions.

That leaves the `isb`. Its purpose is to be a "context synchronization event" (see the Architecture Reference Manual under "Synchronization and coherency issues between data and instruction accesses"), which is what is needed to flush any prefetched instructions.  But the `eret` instruction that returns from the kernel to user space already counts as such an event, so that's automatically taken care of.

The same thing would happen if you replace your steps 4-7 of your second sequence with a call to `mprotect`, to simply set execute permission on the memory that's already there.

In the case  of `munmap`, a cache flush shouldn't actually be needed.  It is going to unmap those pages and flush the TLBs, and it gets a free context synchronization event from `eret` as before.  That means that any future attempt to execute at that address will take a page fault, and so it doesn't matter what bits are actually in the icache line.

As far as I know, the only time you would need to do the cache flushing and `isb` in user space is if you want to write the code into some block of memory and then immediately branch there, like a JIT compiler might do, without a mmap/mprotect call in between.  That could be done with a `PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC` mapping (though I'm not sure if all kernels allow that these days); or by "aliasing" - mapping the same physical memory at two different virtual addresses, with different permissions.  See [AArch64 memory synchronization operations on multiply-mapped addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995379/aarch64-memory-synchronization-operations-on-multiply-mapped-addresses/73009027#73009027) and [Synchronizing caches for JIT/self-modifying code on ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635862/synchronizing-caches-for-jit-self-modifying-code-on-arm/70684882#70684882).

Comment: Those links are for AArch64, ARMv6 and later are the same. ARMv4 and ARMv5 have VIVT caches which are cleaned and invalidated on every context switch and `munmap`.